# Accidentally merged github repo into personal project

Tags: git, github

I accidentally pulled a github repo into a personal project in the same folder as my .git. This has had the effect of intertwining the commits from the repo with my project.  Now instead of 30ish commits, I have 600.  Is there a good method to extricate these two sets of commits.  Can I delete (and deleting them would be fine) the commits with a different author name?

Rebasing isn't really an option because I often push to a public repo and that would cause the two sets of commits to be significantly out of sync.

Comment: Have you pushed yet?

Comment: These two statements: "Rebasing isn't really an option" and "and deleting them would be fine" seem contradictory. Are you okay with rewriting history or not?

Comment: I want to remove the accidental commits whole-cloth while maintaining the history of 'my' commits and the other project that commits that aren't related to this mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up on:

I used `git rebase --interactive master` to rebase onto the end of the branch.  I then manually deleted the commits that weren't part of the original project.  I also used `squash` quite a bit.  Finally, I had to resolve some merging issue using `git checkout --theirs|--ours`.  This was pretty tedious but it seems like a solid solution.

Hope that can help someone.

Answer (score 3):

If you can find the point in which those commits started to diverge (that is, if you can find the last commit that *you* authored), then you can move the tip of master to that specific commit, and force-push it.

What this means in layman's terms:

With these commits, square denoting the ones you've created, and curly denoting the ones introduced:

```
 [ ] ---- [ ] ---- [ ] ---- [ ] ---- { } ---- { } ---- { } ...
                                                        ^
```

...you want to be able to reset to your latest commit.

```
git reset --hard <SHA>


 [ ] ---- [ ] ---- [ ] ---- [ ] ---- { } ---- { } ---- { } ...
                             ^
```

At this point, you would force-push your branch.

```
git push --force
```

The history on the remote would appear as if those other commits had never occurred.

Comment: `git push --force` scares me but I think that could work.  The issue is that I created a couple of valid commits after the accidental ones.E.g.
`[ ]-----[ ]----{ }----{ }-----[ ] ----- [ ]`.  In fact, its more like `{ }----{ }-----[ ]-----[ ]` because most of the accidental commits seem to have inserted themselves before mine.